# Scoreboard does not update when variables change

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I was making a plugin called choice chamber based off the game, and when I wanted to create a scoreboard I put the variables in for a timer. since there was a string with the variables I did not want to use the plain red text of the scoreboard. So I decided to use a score to display the timer, but I soon ran into a problem. I don't know how to update the score so the correct time is shown. Right now I have the score being printed to chat for debugging an issue. thanks!

Here is my code:

```js
package main;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.DisplaySlot;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Objective;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Score;
import org.bukkit.scoreboard.Scoreboard;

public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    int secondTimer = 30;
    int minuteTimer = 0;
    boolean running = false;


    public void onEnable() {

        getLogger().info("***********************");
        getLogger().info("Choice Chamber Enabled");
        getLogger().info("Choice Chamber V. " + getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("Choice Chamber").getDescription().getVersion());
        getLogger().info("Written By @McMattGames");
        getLogger().info("***********************");

    }

    public void onDisable() {

        getLogger().info("***********************");
        getLogger().info("Choice Chamber Disabled");
        getLogger().info("***********************");

    }

    //commands
    @EventHandler
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
        secondTimer = 30;
        minuteTimer = 0;
        if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("choice") || cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            Scoreboard board = getServer().getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
            Objective objective = board.registerNewObjective("timer", "dummy");
            Score score = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GREEN + "Timer: ");
            Score score2 = objective.getScore(ChatColor.GREEN + "" + minuteTimer + ":" + secondTimer);
            objective.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Choice Chamber");
            objective.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);
            score.setScore(-1);
            score2.setScore(-2);
            if (sender instanceof Player) {
                if (args.length > 0) {
                    Player p = (Player) sender;
                    if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
                        if (running == !true) {
                            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] Round Starting!");
                            running = true;
                            p.setScoreboard(board);
                            Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(this, new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    secondTimer = secondTimer - 1;
                                    if (secondTimer <= 0) {
                                        minuteTimer = minuteTimer - 1;
                                        secondTimer = 59;
                                    }
                                    if (minuteTimer < 0) {
                                        Bukkit.getServer().getScheduler().cancelAllTasks();
                                        Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] Round Over!");
                                        running = false;
                                    }
                                    if (minuteTimer >= 0) {
                                        if (secondTimer > 9) {
                                            getServer().broadcastMessage(minuteTimer + ":" + secondTimer);
                                        } else {
                                            getServer().broadcastMessage(minuteTimer + ":0" + secondTimer);
                                        }
                                    }

                                }
                            }, 0, 20);
                        } else {
                            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Round Already Started");
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("join")) {
                            if (running == true) {

                                p.setScoreboard(board);
                                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + "Joining");
                            } else {
                                p.sendMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "No Game Started!");

                            }
                        } else {
                            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.GOLD + "Choice Chamber" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.RED + "Invalad Command!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explicitly update the scoreboard, simply changing the variable's contents won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The default scoreboard system of the Bukkit is flickering if you update it, so you should use the SpigotLibs ScoreboardAPI for coding your Scoreboard system.
https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/spigotlib.5925/

If you need additional help, you can contact me on Skype: gyurixdev